# How to handle more then 1 error Handler's in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

Please find my below error handle code.

```
Sub trial()
On Error GoTo MyHandler
s = 15 / 0
MyHandler:
s = 0

On Error GoTo my2Handler
h = 10 / 0
Handler:
h = 0

End Sub
```

My second error handler i.e. **my2Handler** is not working and i am not able to use both the error handler's in 1 sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Resume` as below:

```
Sub trial()

Check1:
    On Error GoTo MyHandler
    s = 15 / 0

Check2:
    On Error GoTo my2Handler
    h = 10 / 0

Exit Sub

MyHandler:
    s = 0
    Resume Check2

my2Handler:
    h = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but if there is no error for getting value in s calculation then my code will not go to 2nd error handler i.e **my2Handler** so can i deal with both the error handler separably.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have the label for `my2Handler` they both need to go at the bottom to as MyHandler will always be called, like so

```
Sub twoerrors()

On Error GoTo Handler1

'   do something

On Error GoTo Handler2

'   do something else
Exit Sub

Handler1:
    Exit Sub

Handler2:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```